# Picture by R' Aryeh Kaplan on the front cover of the Aryeh Kaplan Reader

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, symbols-symbology, art, rabbi-aryeh-kaplan

Hello does anyone know of anyone I could contact or where I could look with regard to an explanation of the painting on the front of the Aryeh Kaplan Reader by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan himself?

[image: Aryeh Kaplan Reader Cover]

Comment: Rabbi Kaplan passed away years ago; maybe try the publisher.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) B First. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: His widow (Yocheved?) might have some information; I believe she resides in Brooklyn.

Comment: Or his nine children@Oliver

Answer (score 10):

Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan was among many things a painter. He mentioned this in his book *Jewish Meditation* (p. 29):

> I also remember a period during which I was painting. I had just learned how to use acrylics and had found that I could produce a fairly decent piece of work. Whenever I got involved in a painting, it seemed that I was also "locked on" to the project; I would find it extremely difficult to leave it. Again, I was able to create paintings that we surprising even to me. It appeared that when I was creating, I as going into a higher state of consciousness. Subjectively, I did not simply feel a sense of great awareness or alertness; rather I felt as if I were thinking in an entirely different mode.

This [article](https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/arts-letters/articles/the-hasidic-underground) mentions:

> His dining room was adorned with a series of bizarre oil paintings. At some point, with no training as an artist, Kaplan decided to refrain from study for a year and devote himself to painting. After the year he stopped and never painted again. Those paintings were the product of his experiment.

See [Yated Ne'eman, January 25, 2013, p. 55](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g_Jserffbke_i7Tc1svAwF3ZWNghKgwn/view?usp=sharing):

> Not only was he a genius, posits Rabbi Mendelson, he was multitalented and multi-faceted. He was
> an expert artist who painted his
> own original masterpieces, and
> retouched the ancient paintings
> displayed on the jacket-covers of
> “The Torah Anthology.” He was
> an expert ceramist, carpenter and
> stone-designer, and he was an expert biologist and botanist.

At the thirtieth anniversary of his passing, his son started a Facebook page in order to raise money and the like to fund a *Sefer Torah* in his memory.

On that Facebook page he also posted different pictures and paintings from his father. [Here is the post](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=117344975109481&set=a.117344958442816&type=3) of the [seemingly] original copy of that painting.

<sub>(It’s no longer an active Facebook page, as far as I can tell)</sub>

Comment: Wow. So not the answer I was expecting!